# SDL Window does not show even with Event Loop

Tags: c++, window, sdl

I know this question has been asked before but most of the time answer was just to add delay or an event loop. However I have added an event loop and the window ist not showing. Only the console. I am running this program in Visual Studio 2019.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GL/glew.h"

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include "SDL.h"

int main() {

    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    //fenster erstellen
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("C++ OpenGL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    //opengl context setzen
    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    bool close = false;
    while (!close) {

        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                close = true;
            }
        }

        if (close) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `SDL_MainReady` as you are not using `SDL_main`.

See [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady#SDL_SetMainReady-1)

So you code would be adjusted like

```
int main() {
    SDL_Window* window;

    SDL_SetMainReady();
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    ...

    return 0;
}
```